# How should I construct an Oracle function, or other code, to measure time for business processes between two records

Tags: oracle, function, time, calculation

I need suggestions for designing tables and records in Oracle to handle business processes, status, and report times between statuses.

We have a transaction table that records an serial numbered record id, a document id, a date and time, and a status.  Statuses reflect where a document is in the approval process, reflecting a task that needs to be done on a document.  There are up to 40 statuses, showing both who needs to approve and what is the task being done.  So there is a document header or parent record, and multiple status records as child records.

The challenge is to analyzes where bottlenecks are, which tasks are taking the longest, etc.

From a business pov, a task receives a document, we have the date and time this happens.  We do not have a release or finish date and time for a current task.  All we have is the next task's start date and time.  Note that a document can only have one status at a time.

For reasons I won't go into, we cannot use ETL to create an end date and time for a status, although I think that is the solution.

Part of the challenge is that statuses are not entirely consecutive or have a fixed order.  Some statuses can start, stop, and later in the process start again.

What I would like to report is the time, on a weekly or monthly basis, that each status record takes, time date time end minus date time start.  Can anyone suggest a function or other way to accomplish this?

I don't need specific code.  I could use some example in pseudo code or just in outline form of how to solve this.  Then I could figure out the code.

Comment: When a status starts again, what happens to the start date? Is it updated ? Or is it like a log of actions and you just insert a new row for this status?

Comment: The source system adds a row, gives that row the date and time it was created, but does not end the open status.  Again, we are not allowed an ETL or other means to add an end date and time to the previous status record.

Comment: So I need a function or some way to read a status record, ceheck for a younger status record, and if one exists, use its start date time as the end date ant time.  I forgot to mention, there can only be one open status at a time.  As a new status comes in, the current open status is considered as closed.

Comment: Let me be more precise as I read your post.  The status table is like a log of actions.  We just insert a new ow.  Thanks for your post.

Comment: Since every insert means an end time for a status, you can make it work i think. Sort the table by date, and iterate over records. Using a pipelined function with parallel enabled would give you what you want to achieve, but since you said no etl..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trigger after insert and after update on  transaction table to record on a **LOG_TABLE** every change: id transaction, last status, new status, who approve, change date-time (maybe using TiMESTAMP data type is fractional seconds care), terminal, session ID, username.

For insert: you need to define a type of "**insert status**", diferent for other 40 statuses. For example, is status are of numeric type, a "insert status" can be "**-1**" (minus one), so last status is "**-1**" and new status is status of the inserted record on transaction table.

With this **LOG_TABLE** you can develop a package with functions to calculate time between changed status, display all changes, dispplay last change, etc.